# How to clear selected option in angular-ui select on button click

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I need to clear the selected option in angular ui-slect when clicking on clear button  , the options i saw mainly are using the allow clear (x-icon) . Can someone please tell me how to do the same on click of my clear button. 
Below is my code :

```
 <form name = "Studform" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="search(stud.search.id,stud.search.country)">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 bottom-buffer">
          <div class="row form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Country</label>
            <div class="col-xs-6 ">
              <ui-select id= "country" ng-model="ctry" name= "country"  theme="bootstrap">
                <ui-select-match >{{text || $select.selected.id}}</ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="countryL in countryLookup | filter: $select.search">
                  <div ng-bind-html="countryL.id | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                  <small ng-bind-html="countryL.name | highlight: $select.search"></small>
                </ui-select-choices>
              </ui-select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class ="col-xs-2 col-md-2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12" align="right">
          <button type="button" ng-click="clear()" class="btn btn-default " >Clear</button>
          <button type="button" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" ng-click="search(ctryval)" >Search</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>



  $scope.clear = function () {
          $scope.ctry = undefined;
        //did not work 
        };
```

Comment: did you try $scope.selected = {} ?

Comment: do you get an error in console?

Comment: no error in console. But ng-model value is showing as undefined inside clear ()

Comment: $scope.selected ={} did not work

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work:

```
  $scope.clear = function () {
     delete $scope.ctry;
  };
```

Try this then since first did not work:

HTML

```
    <ui-select id= "country.selected" ng-model="ctry" name= "country" theme="bootstrap">
    ...
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="clear($event)">X</button>
```

JS

```
$scope.clear = function($event) {
   $event.stopPropagation(); 
   $scope.ctry.selected = undefined; 
};
```

Comment: no,it didnt .. Do I need to set any attribute in my ui-select tag to clear selected option ?

Answer (score 0):

ui-select now provides the clearing button / feature.

All you need to do is to set `allow-clear` attribute.

```
<ui-select-match allow-clear>
...
</ui-select-match>
```